# how do I export my results in excel from Jullia?

Tags: julia

How can I export my tables in Excel from Julia?
my table is  a matrix as bellow:

```
x y z e r t b
1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

I want to write it in a excel sheet. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Write as CSV. All spreadsheets are able to import this format

Comment: Could you please state exactly what your original data is? Your example has mixture of letters and numbers - so it is probably not a matrix.

Comment: In fact, it is a `Matrix{Any}`, i.e. a matrix in the Julia type sense :) I still second your statement of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your table as (i.e. ignoring that it contains strings as well as integers)

```
julia> table = ["x" "y" "z" "e" "r" "t" "b";
       1 0 1 1 0 1 1;
       0 1 1 0 1 1 1;
       1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
4×7 Array{Any,2}:
  "x"   "y"   "z"   "e"   "r"   "t"   "b"
 1     0     1     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     0     0     0     1
```

you can use Julia's [writecsv](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.DataFmt.writecsv), i.e. `writecsv("mytable.csv", table)`.

For more complex data you should consider using [DataFrames](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl) and [CSV.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl) for CSV export.

UPDATE: There is also [Taro.jl](http://aviks.github.io/Taro.jl/guide/hssf/) which allows one (through some Java API) to write Excel files on individual cell level.

Comment: would you please say, can I write table in another sheet?
for example I have 5 table and I want to write every table in a sheet of the mytable file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine working (in excel or in libreoffice) with the ods format you can use [OdsIO.jl](https://github.com/sylvaticus/OdsIO.jl).
You can specify the exact cell location, so for example you can update with the new data only the cell region of interest.